# Reuse Load Balancer for K8s Services

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have just set up my first K8s cluster in Oracle Cloud. And have a website running in it.
Is there a way to use one LB instead of creating one for each K8s service?

Take a look at this code from the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengcreatingloadbalancer.htm)
Here we create a LB only for this service. I would like to create one LB for my K8s Services so I only have to set up TSL in one place. So can I in the Deployment file point to an existing LB or do I just create the service and then point the LB at the service?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx-svc
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx
```

Comment: I think the best way to go would be using an ingress, see [oci docs on that here](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/ContEng/Tasks/contengsettingupingresscontroller.htm) and the [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) for how to create entries for multiple services.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible: OKE will always create a new load balancer for each new exposed service.

Regards